# Creating an ifelse() statement with startsWith() condition on one variable to change another variable

Tags: r, if-statement, grepl

I have a dataset where I'd like to use an `ifelse()` statement that has some sort of `startsWith()` condition to change another variable.

In plain English it would essentially be "if ID starts with 13 then variable_X == 1"

I understand that `grepl` has the capability to search through like this but I am unsure how to output a result onto a new or existing variable.

Any ideas on how to begin with this? Thank you!

EDIT: Apologies, as I forgot to mention a crucial detail. There are multiple ID's ranging from 13, 14, 15, 16, etc. I'd like to have my "If ID starts with 13 then variable X == 1" but the else is "do nothing" as to not overlap with over ID numbers. I've also attached a sample dataset showing what I have currently.

```r
ID <- c('13-432', '13-342', '13-546', '14-442', '14-543', 
        '15-332', '15-153', '16-323', '16-654', '16-554')
Outcome <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(ID, Outcome)
```

```
       ID Outcome
1  13-432       1
2  13-342       1
3  13-546       1
4  14-442       2
5  14-543       2
6  15-332       3
7  15-153       2
8  16-323       3
9  16-654       2
10 16-554       2
```

Comment: Try `with(df1, ifelse(startsWith(ID, "13"), 1, variable_X))`

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` way of doing this could be

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(ID = c("131", "140"))

dat |> mutate(variable_X = if_else(startsWith(ID, "13"), 1, 0))
```

Output

```r
#>    ID variable_X
#> 1 131          1
#> 2 140          0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is good, thanks! One question that I should have included in the original post (and will edit). This will be done multiple times over for different ID's starting with 13, 14, 15, etc.. So I am wondering how to set the `else` condition to keeping the variable as is ,that way I don't overwrite the other ID's with another value.

Comment: Please edit the question to add a sample of your dataset and the expected output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.